# Reading a binary map file in r

Tags: r, binary, geospatial

I am trying to read a binary file in R containing a simple 2D array of 360x180 values. For reference, the binary file can be found here:

http://transcom.project.asu.edu/download/transcom03/smoothmap.fix.2.bin

Here is what the readme for this .bin says:

> The file 'smoothmap.fix.2.bin' contains a single real, binary  array
>   dimensioned 360 x 180. The array contains the numbers 1  through 22,
>   denoting each of the 22 basis functions in the  TransCom 3 experiment.
>   This file was written on an SGI Origin  2000 hosting UNIX.

And my code:

```
to.read <- file("smoothmap.fix.2.bin", "rb")
raw.transcom <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n = 360*180, size = 4, endian = "big")
transcom <- matrix(raw.transcom, 180, 360, byrow = F)
```

Now raw.transcom contains only junk values:

```
unique(raw.transcom)
 [1]     259200          0 1101004800 1082130432 1092616192 1097859072 1100480512 1102053376 1086324736
[10] 1077936128 1101529088 1095761920 1096810496 1099956224 1091567616 1084227584 1090519040 1094713344
[19] 1099431936 1073741824 1093664768 1088421888 1065353216 1098907648
```

Why would that be?

I've been looking at this for an hour now and I'm stumped. Played around with endian-ness settings and the 'size' in readBin, but that did not help.

How can I read in this file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I didn't have time to poke at the "R" way to do this, but I do have access to GDL and found [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.idl-pvwave/reading-binary-file-with-read_binary/2090312), so I threw together:

```
Data  = read_binary('smoothmap.fix.2.bin',DATA_TYPE=4,ENDIAN='big');
Data = Data[1:64800]
Data = reform(Data,[360,180])

openw,unit,'testfile.dat',/get_lun
printf,unit,Data
free_lun,unit
```

and managed to generate: http://rud.is/dl/testfile.dat.gz

If you grab that and do:

```
x <- as.numeric(scan("testfile.dat.gz", "numeric"))

length(x)
## [1] 64800

table(x)
##   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22 
## 7951 1643 1189  796  868 1688  864 2345 2487  509  733 1410 5144 2388 2433 4111 7617 2450 1671 2058 9161 2334 2950
```

It definitely looks like it's got the right values for the definition you specified and you can turn that into a matrix.

Check back, though, as I now *need* to figure out how to do this in R :-)

---

**UPDATE**

GOT IT!

I'm rly kinda glad I found the IDL code to verify the R results.

```
x <- readBin("smoothmap.fix.2.bin", "raw", file.size("smoothmap.fix.2.bin"))
x <- x[-(1:4)]
x <- x[-((length(x)-3):length(x))]

table(readBin(rawConnection(x), "numeric", 360*180, 4, endian="big"))
##    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22 
## 7951 1643 1189  796  868 1688  864 2345 2487  509  733 1410 5144 2388 2433 4111 7617 2450 1671 2058 9161 2334 2950
```

Ideally, we'd check for first 4 and last 4 bytes being equal, but this hack shld get you through.

---

**Putting it all together**

Added validation bits of code…

```
#' Read in a binary array, likely written with IDL
#' 
#' @param x path to file (auto-expanded & tested for existence)
#' @param n number of `float` elements to read in
#' @param endian endian-ness (default `big`)
#' @return numeric vector of length `n`
read_binary_float <- function(x, n, endian="big") {

  x <- normalizePath(path.expand(x))

  x <- readBin(con = x, what = "raw", n = file.size(x))

  first4 <- x[1:4] # extract front bits
  last4 <- x[(length(x)-3):length(x)] # extract back bits

  # convert both to long ints      

  f4c <- rawConnection(first4)
  on.exit(close(f4c), add=TRUE)
  f4 <- readBin(con = f4c, what = "integer", n = 1, size = 4L, endian=endian)

  l4c <- rawConnection(last4)      
  on.exit(close(l4c), add=TRUE)      
  l4 <- readBin(con = l4c, what = "integer", n = 1, size = 4L, endian=endian)

  # validation

  stopifnot(f4 == l4) # check front/back are equal
  stopifnot(f4 == n*4) # check if `n` matches expected record count

  # strip off front and back bits

  x <- x[-(1:4)]
  x <- x[-((length(x)-3):length(x))]

  # slurp it all in

  rc <- rawConnection(x)      
  on.exit(close(rc), add=TRUE)

  readBin(con = rc, what = "numeric", n = n, size = 4L, endian=endian)

}
```

Quick example:

```
library(magrittr)

read_binary_float("smoothmap.fix.2.bin", 360*180) %>% 
  matrix(nrow = 360, ncol = 180) %>% 
  image()
```

[image]

This file seems to conform to the Fortran "unformatted I/O" spec : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnc4/index.html : which confirmed the

```
"# records" | record | record | … | record | "# records"
```

we saw. So the function could be generalized to support more than just `float` conversion:

```
read_binary_array <- function(x, type=c("byte", "integer", "float"), endian="big") {

  type <- match.arg(trimws(tolower(type)), c("byte", "integer", "float"))
  type_size <- unname(c("byte"=1, "integer"=4, "float"=4)[type])

  x <- normalizePath(path.expand(x))

  x <- readBin(con = x, what = "raw", n = file.size(x))

  first4 <- x[1:4]
  last4 <- x[(length(x)-3):length(x)]

  f4c <- rawConnection(first4)
  on.exit(close(f4c), add=TRUE)
  f4 <- readBin(con = f4c, what = "integer", n = 1, size = 4L, endian=endian)

  l4c <- rawConnection(last4)
  on.exit(close(l4c), add=TRUE)
  l4 <- readBin(con = l4c, what = "integer", n = 1, size = 4L, endian=endian)

  stopifnot(f4 == l4) # check front/back are equal
  stopifnot((f4 %% type_size == 0)) # shld have nothing left over

  n_rec <- f4 / type_size
  message(sprintf("Reading in %s records...", scales::comma(n_rec)))

  x <- x[-(1:4)]
  x <- x[-((length(x)-3):length(x))]

  rc <- rawConnection(x)
  on.exit(close(rc), add=TRUE)

  what <- switch(type, byte="raw", integer="integer", float="numeric")
  dat <- readBin(con = rc, what = what, n = n_rec, size = type_size, endian=endian)

  dat

}
```

Comment: I found `packBits(intToBits(d[4321])[c(32:20,1:19)], type='integer')` rather early, and spent ***a lot*** of time trying to honor the original statement *"contains the numbers 1 through 22"*. I'll post my incomplete R answer for reference.

Comment: thx @r2evans. I suspect this file was written with IDL and boy does that have weird input/output conventions (e.g. https://github.com/cenit/GDL/blob/master/src/pro/read_binary.pro)

Comment: Dang, hrbrmstr, them's ninja skills!

Comment: You're a god. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked! ticking the answer box helps others know this did, indeed, work (though I do hope these files are becoming rarer entities)

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***This is incomplete, posted for progress.***

There might be an undocumented "feature" in the data file, in that the first eight bytes are not part of the data. (The file is 259208, but `360*180*4==259200`.) However, I do find something else interesting:

```
d <- readBin(file("~/Downloads/smoothmap.fix.2.bin", "rb"), integer(), n = 360*180, size = 4, endian = "big")

head(d)
# [1] 259200      0      0      0      0      0
```

I'm going to infer that the first 4-byte integer (`259200`) indicates the size of the data, so I suggest we can discard it. You might argue that you have the proper length of a vector here, but that's because you forced `readBin` to stop loading data. From [`?readBin`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readBin.html):

> ```
>    n: integer.  The (maximal) number of records to be read.  You
>       can use an over-estimate here, but not too large as storage
>       is reserved for 'n' items.
> ```

So it should be safe to read beyond your expected file size, it will handle EOF by itself. I'll increase by 10, arbitrarily:

```
length(d)
# [1] 64800
d <- readBin(file("~/Downloads/smoothmap.fix.2.bin", "rb"), integer(), n = 360*180+10, size = 4, endian = "big")
length(d)
# [1] 64802
tail(d)
# [1] 1098907648 1098907648 1098907648 1098907648 1098907648     259200
```

(Note that even though I suggested reading another 10 bytes, only two more were available. So you know, the rationale for the `n` argument is for pre-allocation of memory, nothing more.) That `259200` is there again, I'll infer that confirms the end of data, so we should be able to safely discard those two (first/last) numbers.

```
d <- d[-c(1, length(d))]
```

The first non-zero number is:

```
head(which(d>0))
# [1] 4321 4322 4323 4324 4325 4326
d[4321]
# [1] 1101004800
```

and looking at the bits:

```
intToBits(d[4321])
#  [1] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 01
# [26] 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
```

So if you infer a direct binary interpretation, that value is 2820, which doesn't match the `smoothmap.readme` description of available values. Furthermore, what we are expecting to see:

```
intToBits(22)
#  [1] 00 01 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

So it appears that your bits are ... not in the right order, or something like that. If you `intToBits` all unique values, you'll notice that all bits 1-19 (the least-significant bits) are zero.

From here, I'm at a loss ...

```
sapply(unique(d), function(a) packBits(rev(intToBits(a)), type="integer"))
#  [1]    0 1410  258 1154 3714 6530 3458  770  514 5506 2690 1666 2434 2178 1282  130  642 4482    2 3202 1794  508  386
```

Comment: interestingly enough, the first 4 bytes are at the end, too: `c(head(y, 4), tail(y, 4))` == `[1] 00 03 f4 80 00 03 f4 80`

Comment: I think that's what I found, both 259200 (number of other 4-byte numbers).