# reading .MAP and .ID files into R

Tags: r

I am trying to read the files from this website: http://www.education.vic.gov.au/Documents/about/research/datavic/dv280-schoolzones2020.zip into R, specifically the MAP and ID files.

I have tried a few packages that looked like they might help, like `MAPS`, `mapdata` but I can't find any way to read them.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **readBin()** and read it binary, due to the fact that the files are binary you should read them as ones and then you will be able to perform some manipulation that fits the type of data you expect.

After downloading the .zip file and tried to open one sample .map file; the results are:

```
Data = readBin('Secondary_Integrated_Year10_2020.map', "raw", file.size('Secondary_Integrated_Year10_2020.map'))

> head(Data)
[1] 00 0a 0e 15 0e 16
> typeof(Data)
[1] "raw"
```

For example, in the following link the .map file contains data related to the world map. So, after reading the binary file, they performed manipulation to reconstruct the underlying information: [Reading a binary map file in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947793/reading-a-binary-map-file-in-r)

Is that what  you intended in your question?